# c++ how to split array element

Tags: arrays, c++-cli

I have an array with one element, words in array are separated by tab (tab-key):

```
cli::array<String^> ^ PnkFld = {"Good    bye  cruel world"};
```

and program output should look like this with words being split in separate elements:

```
cli::array<String^> ^ PnkFld  = {"Good","bye","cruel","world"};
```

Comment: You need to split the single string on *white-space*. Look around the Internet a little, preferably using your favorite search engine, and you will find quite a lot of examples of how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the [`String::Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) method. If you don't specify any parameters, you'll get [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) overload, which splits on whitespace when the parameter contains no characters.